# Built in option of emailing client after submitting contact form

Tags: magento-1.8, email, contact-us

Is there a built in option in magento of emailing the client after submitting the contact form?

I can't find anything like it..

Comment: Doesn't the contact form just fire off an email to whatever contact email contact you have setup? So emailing them could be as simple as hitting the reply button in your email client. Unless you mean sending a CC to them of the message they just sent. If so that could be accomplished by digging into the contact form and extending it through a custom module.

Comment: I want to notify them that there email was sent and another kind of custom message, but the point is that i could edit the message at the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't (as of Magento CE 1.9.1). If you look at the code that sends the contact form email in `Mage_Contacts_IndexController::postAction()` you will see that there is not much room for customization either (except if you want to write your own controller action)

But writing an own module for this is not hard for an experienced Magento developer. It's either writing your own controller action as mentioned before, or writing an observer for the `contacts_index_post_postDispatch` event that checks if a success message has been triggered and then sends another mail with its own email template to the email address in `$request->getPost('email')`

> **Warning:** Depending on how you write this, it could be misused for spam because at this point the email address is not verified and can be anything. Make sure not to include any content of the contact form in the email, keep it generic!